# Am I taking a wrong approach while looking for an academic position in applied areas - brutal criticisms appreciated!

Tags: mathematics, career-path, industry, early-career

After a PhD in pure mathematic, I wanted to do work in applied areas where I could bring in my pure math expertise. So I did two postdocs in computational medical imaging where I could apply my pure math knowledge coupled with machine learning (which I also liked because of my pure math background). **But the reason I wanted to do computational medical imaging were:**

*1) I felt the market for pure math would be hard, and it'd be difficult to obtain a permanent position. However, if I worked in imaging, then my CV would show that I was capable of doing both pure and applied stuff, hence would keep my options open to industry as well.*

*2) I looked through some papers in medical imaging, and **what attracted me was the mathematical tools that they used in these papers**, **but I didn't pay much attention to the actual unsolved problems in medical imaging. It was definitely not like I didn't care about these problems in imaging, but they were not the main reason I got attracted to it.** But I went ahead with the postdoc anyway, but worked mostly on problems that were of somewhat general nature (e.g. problems at the confluence of differential geometry and machine learning, of interest in imaging. I didn't really work with raw images, rather some heavily processed images that'd fit my differential geometric model).*

After finishing these two postdocs, I tried to continue in medical imaging, but for reasons that were not under my control, I couldn't, and thereafter, I tried to switch to industry and worked unsuccessfully in several companies for short times, and currently I'm again looking to move back to academia.

The reason I ask this question here is that, I recently had a long talk with a friend of mine who's also a PhD and successfully transitioned into industrial R&D from applied math/machine learning to autonomous driving. He told me that I took a wrong approach to working in applied areas. The reason to work in applied areas should be *"I want to solve this problem in this applied area (in my case medical imaging)"* as opposed to *"This applied area uses this and that tools, which I'm already familiar with and like using, hence I must like that applied area as well"*. **The second one was my approach, and I'd like to know if I were wrong?** Even to this day, what principally excites me in an applied area is the underlying math I can bring in to solve the problems there, hence in a project, I seek to stay on the theoretical side, rather than the practical one. For example, *I'm definitely more at ease with pen and paper, but I can and do code for a problem that requires machine learning*, but I'm no fan of e.g. keep tuning parameters to obtain the optimal model like they do in data scientist positions (*I had some, didn't feel passionate about and was unsuccessful*) - I rather like to write an algorithm, prove its convergence if needed, and test it on small and gradually bigger datasets. **MY QUESTION: Am I being wrong in my approach?** **Please be brutally honest! Is there a middle ground that I can take, and how? Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: What’s your question? This seems like  a question too dependent on your preferences, we are not the ones to say whether your preferences are right or wrong.

Comment: There is nothing to criticise here. You interests and approaches to research are your own. There is no one-size-fit-all approach for all pure or applied sciences. Different people and groups adopt different viewpoints and use different techniques. Your approach is as good as other. It's not clear from your question why you were not successful, and it's not enough information to suggest an advice.

Comment: Just want to point out that not all data scientist positions are about tuning parameters to obtain the optimal model. There are organizations out there where you aren't constrained to a single problem and instead are exposed to a variety of problems, many of which have limited discussion in the literature and don't have a lot of data to train on, but are still incredibly impactful. I work with multiple pure mathematicians turned applied/engineers and they've found their niche in this space.

Comment: @kjacks21 Tuning parameters was just an example - what I meant to say is that I'm no fan of building models based on already invented algorithms and use several softwares to integrate them into product or deploy the models, what I'm a fan of is actually coming up with a new algorithm. Just an other example, I don't like e.g. writing a code in TensorFlow to implement an RNN, but I like to write down the analytical expression of the cost function of RNN, and understand the gradient vanishing and blowing up problems from the scratch.

Comment: From my own experience and from several interactions with people, data scientist or machine learning researcher positions in industry are not generally of a fundamental nature, but rather utilizing already invented machinery - which I'm no fan of (not saying that's bad or anything like that, but it simply doesn't excite me).

Comment: @Stat_math thank you for clarifying your preference!

Answer (score 8):

If you are making a mistake, it may be in narrowing your focus, closing off opportunities. Especially if it is you who is giving a too-narrow definition of your capabilities.

A math PhD should be able to teach (nearly) any undergraduate math course and many MS level courses. Every college and university teaches math and so needs people to teach those courses. The market is enormous. But for, say, medical imaging, there are few places that are truly interested. While it is also true that your skills should, and do, enable you to work on a vast range of problems, if you exclude those from consideration, or seem to, then your opportunities also close.

In a lot of ways a mathematician is like a Swiss Army Knife, being able to attack many problems, pure and applied, since they have a facility with abstract thought and how things fit together synergistically. But be careful, in any application, that you define yourself in a way that is flexible enough that others can see your potential.

Comment: The way OP describes themselves I thought immediately, "this is the type of person for whom a position would be created, once an employer recognizes their potential". So, that's probably the main issue. They are looking for the wrong kind of positions, where they don't really have a chance to shine. Maybe a stint in consulting might be worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As you pointed out, it's true that a math PhD should be able to teach (nearly) any undergraduate math course and many MS level courses, and I can, too. But this doesn't mean the market is enormous, if you want to get a stable income. I'm in France, and when I look up 'mathematics' or 'mathematician' in any of the standard sites like indeed, glassdoor, or LinkedIn, I get two kinds of jobs: 1) data scientist/machine learning researcher position in industry which has nothing to do with math, and 2) contractual tutor position with 20€/hour salary. Even in the US, (contd)

Comment: (contd)  there're assistant prof. positions, and lecturer positions, and the later ones are called 'fast food positions' in academia from what I hear, as the lecturers are hired to deliver some courses, mostly for a temporary duration.

Having said that, thank you for your suggestion - I try to mention all my experiences in my CV, including pure math, machine learning and medical imaging, but I don't see abundance of jobs calling me. I've so far worked in only one big company (which recently let me go) and the rest are all small startups, who simply didn't value my passion for math.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your comment! Yes I sincerely hope someone recognizes my potential : thanks to my varied background, quite recently I picked up some topics in probability theory and came up with original theoretical results in the domains of nearest neighborhood search ( a subtopic of machine learning), when I was working for a project in a big company, which was more of a fundamental nature.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, your friend is more right than you.

> This applied area uses this and that tools, which I'm already familiar with and like using, hence I must like that applied area as well.

means to me you are interested in the tools, not the application. The employer may think you'll leave if they change the tools. If that happens, they lose the investment on you.

Your friend's approach

> I want to solve this problem in this applied area

means you are interested in the application regardless the tools they use. Your familiarity with the tools is a bonus to them. When and if they switch to another set of tools, they know you'll stay and learn how to use those new tools if necessary. After all, you are a PhD. You must be able to adapt yourself to new technology and tools with your previously acquired knowledge and rigorous math training.

My suggestion, use the combination of the two approaches. Emphasize your friend's approach, but also mention your familiarity with the tools, so the potential employers know you can jump to work right away without much training.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think you're right, I need to actually delve into the unsolved problems in an area first, and then only comes the question of using what tools I know.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing *wrong* with your approach, following along the lines of Dmitry Savostyanov's comment on your original question ("There is nothing to criticise here..."); however, here is another way to frame your thinking on this:

I've been guilty of having a tool, say a hammer, and looking for nails to hit with that hammer. In many cases where a nail wasn't there, but maybe a screw, I still used the hammer since I wasn't familiar with how to use screw drivers. I've also seen many others with this mentality, particularly in my field of computer science. This mentality ultimately limits the types of problems one can work on, can be off-putting to potential collaborators from other disciplines, and may even be detrimental. The book *Range* by David Epstein essentially argues this and has a chapter on "Learning to Drop Your Familiar Tools". One interesting anecdote of how only using tools one is familiar with on a variety of problems is a note by Rita Redberg in JAMA in 2015, that highlighted findings that "...adjusted mortality for high-risk hearth failure and cardiac arrest is lower at teaching hospitals during the cardiology meetings than during the rest of the year." [1]. In other words, patient outcomes were better when cardiac surgeons were away at conferences(!).

I don't think the above fits exactly how you are thinking, but it is related, hence the mention. Another point to make, based on your clarifying comment below:

> Just an other example, I don't like e.g. writing a code in TensorFlow to implement an RNN, but I like to write down the analytical expression of the cost function of RNN, and understand the gradient vanishing and blowing up problems from the scratch.

Is that there are industrial R&D organizations that would benefit from this interest and do fundamental research. A few that come to mind are Facebook AI Research (FAIR) [2] and Google Brain [3]. Government funded labs may also be a good option, depending on the type of lab and the country you live in.

[1] Redberg, Rita F. "Cardiac patient outcomes during national cardiology meetings." JAMA internal medicine 175.2 (2015): 245-245. Link: https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/article-abstract/2038976

[2] https://ai.facebook.com/research/

[3] https://research.google/teams/brain/

Answer (score 3):

Mathematician working in industry here. I'll second [scaaahu's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/150597/4140) and would like to offer an additional point of view.

Industrial employers have problems to solve. They are looking for *solutions*. Tools are only means to an end. As such, they will usually prefer candidates and employees who will use the most appropriate tool to solve the problem at hand - not search for problems they can apply their favorite tool to.

Thus, if the latter is your preferred approach, and especially if you communicate this ("What drew you to the field of medical image processing?" "I was looking for somewhere to apply differential geometry."), you may be limiting your employability. (And incidentally, also your personal growth.)

Of course, this doesn't mean tools are irrelevant. Switching tools such as technologies simply because a particular tool is better for a particular problem may be short-sighted if it requires much upfront/ongoing investment. And knowing tools that help you address problems is always a good thing, and you *can* become a guru for one particular tool. It's just that industry on balance prefers people that are driven by problems and solutions, less so by tools. And if you do go the guru way, you need to make sure your toolset stays in demand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess both academia and industry have problems to solve, but regarding the problems solved in industry though, I feel that because of the limitation on time and finances, the industry would often focus more on "quick and dirty" solution using pre-existing tools, rather than developing a new theory to solve the same. E.g. I've been told in interviews that the data scientists are were encouraged to perform linear regression for simplifying things, even if theoretically it didn't make sense to do so. (contd)

Comment: (contd) "Thus, if the latter is your preferred approach, and especially if you communicate this" It's not like it's my preferred approach, it's just that somewhat subconsciously this is the reason I keep getting attracted to applied areas, e.g. in my last job in telecom company, I was told in the interview that the project might use random matrices, and that made me interested, despite no knowledge of signal processing or telecom. But I think I get your point - I need to point out the actual problems in that area and how I can import my tools to solve them. Thanks again.

Comment: I would put it a little differently. Both industry and academia are trying to solve problems with constrained resources, and therefore, both take shortcuts where appropriate. In industry, this means applying methods even if they are wrong, as long as they work. (You'd be surprised how far a simple and inappropriate linear regression can get you, and it has the advantage of being easy to explain to a non-mathematician programmer, and to a customer.) ...

Comment: ... Conversely, academia takes shortcuts in reducing problems. I work in forecasting, both in business and academically. Academics can get away with throwing away 5% of their time series that are problematic (and mentioning this in the paper, true). The business forecaster can't do that, he has to deal with *all* the data, and those 5% may cause more work than the other 95%. Similarly, academics in general pay much less attention to code quality, testing etc. After all, their code won't run for decades at many customers and potentially cause huge damage if it fails.

Comment: Finally, yes, the problems business and academia attack are different. In academia, advancing theoretical understanding is a value in itself. (It's what you get paid to do.) In business, it isn't. (You won't get paid to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

**Solving applied problems demonstrates your ability and willingness to perform in industry, which is probably more convincing in the job market** in comparison with applying familiar tools, which only shows you have the right skills. You can adjust your self-promotion to improve your chances, e.g., by explaining that applying tools allowed you to hone your skills, which you're now ready to solve problems with. (There's a problem if those tools are now outdated.)

> what principally excites me in an applied area is the underlying math I can bring in to solve the problems there, hence in a project, I seek to stay on the theoretical side, rather than the practical one.

**You need to ask yourself whether transitioning to industry is for you**. (You can be *more at ease with pen and paper*. Industry is awash with cash. You can specialise. Someone else can code, fine tune parameters, etc.) If you want to *stay on the theoretical side*, then why transition?